# Removing a shape from Kinetic.Group

Tags: jquery-ui, kineticjs

I have a `Kinetic.Group` that contains inside of it some shapes and images. I defined a function to delete images on double-click, here's my code :

```
img.on("dblclick dbltap", function (e) {
        if (e.which != 3) {
            img.getParent().listening(false); //the parent here is the group
            var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this equipment?");
            if (r == true) {
               this.remove();
               layer.draw(this);
               stage.add(layer);
               img.getParent().listening(true);
            }
       }
});
```

Knowing that the group has the exact same function for deleting (except of course I'm not calling the listening() method).

```
group.on("dblclick dbltap", function (e) {
    if (e.which != 3) {
        var r = confirm("Do you want to delete this?\n\nWarning: You risk to lose its children.");
        if (r == true) {
            this.removeChildren();
            this.remove();
            layer.draw();
            stage.add(layer);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem comes when I double-click on an image and click ok, so I'm getting two popups:

- the first one is asking to confirm if I want to delete the image
- the second asks if I want to delete the group.

Doesn't `.listening(false);` disable listening to events in KineticJS? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know about the `listening` method, but what about [stopping event propagation](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-cancel-event-bubble-propagation-with-kineticjs/)?

Comment: Oh thank you, didn't know that method before now. Tried it and it worked. You can post it as answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve, is that the event doesn't propagate through the children elements. In KineticJS you can do this with `event.cancelBubble = true;`

So you can you use:

```
group.on('click', function(e) {
    e.cancelBubble = true;
});
```

See [HTML5 Canvas Cancel Event Bubble Propagation with KineticJS](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-cancel-event-bubble-propagation-with-kineticjs/)

Comment: Great! :-) Now I'm curious.. I'll just make some more researches about the uses of `listening` method.

Comment: Glad I could help :). It seems like with [`listening`](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-listen-or-dont-listen-to-events-with-kineticjs/) you can turn off event listeners for elements.